# problem on R subsetting a time series using lubridate and window

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following problem on R : I try to perform an RMSE test for a VAR(10) model,
on a monthly bivariate time series going from november 2003 to november 2022. For this, I
have to subset the data first, to make predictions based on period 2003-2021, for the year
2022, and then compare them to the actual values of 2022.

Yet both the following codes do
not work… Could anyone help ?

```
> library(lubridate)
> library(Metrics)
>
> start_date <- ymd("2003-11-01")
> end_date <- ymd("2021-12-01")
>
> subset_data <- energy.bv[index(energy.bv) >= start_date & index(energy.bv) <=
end_date]

> Modelenergy2_test <- VAR(subset_data, p = 10, season = 12, type = "both")
Error in VAR(subset_data, p = 10, season = 12, type = "both") :
The matrix 'y' should contain at least two variables. For univariate analysis consider
ar() and arima() in package stats.
forecast_2022 <- predict(Modelenergy2_test, n.ahead = 11, ci = 0)
start_date_2022 <- ymd("2022-01-01")
end_date_2022 <- ymd("2022-11-01")
actual_2022 <- energy.bv[index(energy.bv) >= start_date_2022 & index(energy.bv) <=
end_date_2022]
rmse <- RMSE(forecast_2022$Nucléaire[, 1], actual_2022$Nucléaire[, 1])
The second does not work either, as R still doesn’t recognise that 2021 is after 2003 :
library(lubridate)
library(Metrics)
start_date <- ymd("2003-11-01")
end_date <- ymd("2021-12-01")
subset_data <- window(energy.bv, start = start_date, end = end_date)
?windows
# la fonction windows veut que la time series soit en ordre ascendant :
subset_data <- window(rev(energy.bv), start = start_date, end = end_date)
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' ne peut pas être après 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : valeur de 'end' inchangée
Modelenergy2_test <- VAR(subset_data, p = 10, season = 12, type = "both")
forecast_2022 <- predict(Modelenergy2_test, n.ahead = 11, ci = 0)
start_date_2022 <- ymd("2022-01-01")
end_date_2022 <- ymd("2022-11-01")
actual_2022 <- window(energy.bv, start = start_date_2022, end = end_date_2022)
rmse <- RMSE(forecast_2022$Nucléaire[, 1], actual_2022$Nucléaire[, 1])
```

Comment: Just in case: make sure the data (`energy.bv`) is sorted chronologically before feeding it to `window()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.